# Changing a XML element to String

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I was wondering if there is a simple method to change a XML element to a string when using a DOM parser.

I have this bit of code right here:

```
XPathExpression NtryRefexpr = xpath.compile("//Ntfctn/Ntry/NtryRef");
            Object NtryRef = NtryRefexpr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodesNtryRef = (NodeList) NtryRef;
            for(int i = 0; i < nodesNtryRef.getLength(); i++){
                Element NtryRefel = (Element) nodesNtryRef.item(i);
                String element = NtryRefel.toString();
                NtryRefAL.add(element);


            }
```

as you can gather I tried to use .toString() on the XML element. Apparently this did not work because when I go back and try to print the items in the array everything is null. Also when I tried to just print the string "element" it also shows as null.

What is the proper way to convert "element" to a String? The actual value of the element in the XML is just a bunch of numbers.

Comment: If you have `<NtryRef>1 2 3 4</NtryRef>`, which string do you need, only the inner content of the element, that is `1 2 3 4`, or the markup of the complete element, that is `<NtryRef>1 2 3 4</NtryRef>`? You can use `NtryRefel.getTextContent()` to get `1 2 3 4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this figured out through research and help from others.

Below is my code showing how I navigate my nodes, select the node I want and save the attribute to a String. Note that the attribute will contain a lot of extra imformation including the tag name

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><NachaTransCd>27</NachaTransCd>
```

So this must be removed by using substrings and the length method.

Here is my code:

```
XPathExpression CardAcctTpexpr = xpath.compile("//Ntfctn/Ntry/NtryDtls/TxDtls/SplmtryData/Envlp/Cnts/CardAcctTp");
            Object CardAcctTp = CardAcctTpexpr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodesCardAcctTp = (NodeList) CardAcctTp;
            for(int i = 0; i < nodesCardAcctTp.getLength(); i++){
                Element CardAcctTpel = (Element) nodesCardAcctTp.item(i);
                CardAcctTpS = Utilities.xmlToString(CardAcctTpel);
                int length = CardAcctTpS.length();
                CardAcctTpS = CardAcctTpS.substring(50,length);
                length = CardAcctTpS.length();
                CardAcctTpS = CardAcctTpS.substring(0,length-13);
                CardAcctTpAL.add(CardAcctTpS);

            }
```